# Move and resize partitions proportionally

Tags: parted, clonezilla, resize2fs

I have a clonezilla image from a disk with GPT, and I want to clone to a larger disk and then resize the partitions proportionally. By example if I have a 100 Gb disk and two partitions of 40 an 60 Gb, I want to make a clone to another disk of 200 Gb with the result of a 80 and a 120 Gb partitions.

With clonezilla the only way that you can do this is with the -k1 option but only works with MBR disks, is there any other posibility to do this? Maybe the only option is to do a script to:

- View partitions and its porcentages (parted -l?)
- Calculate the new space
- Move the partitions (parted move?)
- Resize the partitions (parted resize?)
- Rebuild the filesystem (e2fsck -f && resize2fs /dev/sdaX)

Answer (score 1):

This is untested by myself but I did find this workaround approach to your problem on the CloneZilla forums.

- [Clone 3T to 4T (migrate) GPT](http://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Clonezilla_live/thread/848e1dfa/)

#### Method #1 (For Windows) - excerpt

> > I need to migrate WD 3T (hard disk 1 partition, GPT table and NTFS, BASIC) to Seagate 4T (create the partition table in the destination disk and try to create the partition table on the destination disk proportionally to have only 1 partition 4T)
> >
> > Do last clonezilla versión support that? 3t to 4t GPT 
> >     What restore options should i use?
> >
> > Thank you very much
>
> (I tested by default and the result was 4T "3T with WD3T DATA and 1T unformated")
>
> **EDIT:** Stable Clonezilla live (2.1.2-20) do not resize automatically 3T to 4T during migration. But, here is a solution:
>
> 1. use Clonezilla liveCD 2.1.2-20 to migrate Clone (device-devide) 3T to 4T. The result is HDD(4T)=3T(with original data "cloned")+1T (unformated). 6 hours.
> 2. In Windows 7 (64bit) install Minitool Partition Wizard Home Edition (is free!!) and resize HDD(4T) to full space... 30 seconds!

**NOTE:** Here's a link to [Minitool](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), the referenced tool above.

#### Method #2 (For Unix) - excerpt

> Another method is you use `cgdisk` to create the GPT partition table on the destination disk. Make sure all the partitions are equal or larger than the source ones. Then you can use Clonezilla live to do local disk to disk cloning. Remember to enter expert mode, and choose "-k" option so that the partition table you have just created could be use.

#### Method #3 (For Unix)

Several other approaches (3 actually) are highlighted in the CloneZilla FAQ under the question titled:[How can I restore the image from small harddisk to larger one ?](http://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/26_resize.faq#26_resize.faq). The Method #2 I found in the forum post above is actually the 1st choice from this list as well, i.e. using GParted to resize after the cloning.

*excerpt*

> 1. Save the image in the Clonezilla server.
> 2. Do a normal restoration to target machine by clonezilla.
> 3. When clone is finished, use `gparted` to resize or move the partition. You can install `gparted` in the DRBL server, then boot the client into remote-linux-gra (dcs -> remote-linux-gra) mode, login client as root, run `gparted` to do that. Or you can use gparted LiveCD or LiveUSB to do that. A gparted-clonezilla dual boot live CD is available, for more info, check http://gparted.free.fr/GParted-Clonezilla/ or http://www.icewalkers.com/jump.php?AID=2917&src=home.